# filling in missing value from lagged value in R

Tags: r, repeat

I have a dataframe like this:

```
ID     year  mstat change lint
8049    1995    1   NA    NA
8049    1996    1   0     1994
8049    1997    1   NA    NA
8049    1998    1   0     1996
8049    1999    1   NA    NA
8049    2000    1   0     1998
8049    2001    1   NA      NA
8049    2002    1   0     2000
8049    2003    NA  NA    NA
8049    2004    NA  NA    NA
8049    2005    NA  NA    NA
8049    2006    NA  NA    NA
8049    2007    NA  NA    NA
8049    2008    1   0     2002
8049    2009    NA  NA    NA
8049    2010    1   0     2008
8049    2011    NA  NA    NA
8049    2012    2   1     2008
8049    2013    NA  NA    NA
```

1. mstat=marital status,
2. lint=last interview date
3. change=change in marital status

For a particular individual, the last interview date in `year=2008` is `2002`. and the change in marital status in `year=2008` is `0`. It means that marital status from 2003 through 2007 should be the same as marital status in 2002 or in 2008. How can I fill in `mstat` from 2003 through 2007 using 2002/2008 `mstat` for this individual as well as for the entire dataset in R? (For different individuals the missing values are in different years. )

My desired output is (in the `mstat_updated` column, from 2003 through 2007, is 1.)

```
 ID   year mstat change lint mstat_updated
8049   2000 1   0       1998    1
8049   2001 1   NA      NA      1
8049   2002 1   0       2000    1
8049   2003 NA  NA      2002    1
8049   2004 NA  NA     2002     1
8049   2005 NA  NA      2002    1
8049   2006 NA  NA      2002    1
8049   2007 NA  NA      2002    1
8049   2008 1   0       2002    1
8049   2009 NA  NA      2008    1
8049   2010 1   0       2008    1
8049   2011 NA  NA      2010    NA
8049   2012 2   1       2010    2
```

After trying out the code as Ben suggested I get the following table where all the `change` values are `TRUE`.

```
df %>%
  fill(lint, .direction = 'up') %>%
  group_by(lint) %>%
  mutate(anychange = any(change > 0),
         mstat_updated = ifelse(anychange, mstat, last(mstat)))




ID    year  mstat change lint anychange mstat_updated
8049    1992    1   1   1991    TRUE    1
8049    1993    1   0   1992    TRUE    1
8049    1994    1   0   1993    TRUE    1
8049    1995    NA  NA  1994    TRUE    NA
8049    1996    1   0   1994    TRUE    1
8049    1997    NA  NA  1996    TRUE    NA
8049    1998    1   0   1996    TRUE    1
8049    1999    NA  NA  1998    TRUE    NA
8049    2000    1   0   1998    TRUE    1
8049    2001    NA  NA  2000    TRUE    NA
8049    2002    1   0   2000    TRUE    1
8049    2003    NA  NA  2002    TRUE    NA
8049    2004    NA  NA  2002    TRUE    NA
8049    2005    NA  NA  2002    TRUE    NA
8049    2006    NA  NA  2002    TRUE    NA
8049    2007    NA  NA  2002    TRUE    NA
8049    2008    1   0   2002    TRUE    1
8049    2009    NA  NA  2008    TRUE    NA
8049    2010    1   0   2008    TRUE    1
8049    2011    NA  NA  2008    TRUE    NA
8049    2012    2   1   2008    TRUE    2
8049    2013    NA  NA  2012    TRUE    NA
8049    2014    3   1   2012    TRUE    3
8049    2015    NA  NA  2014    TRUE    NA
8049    2016    3   0   2014    TRUE    3


 head(df,20L)
       ID    year  mstat change  lint anychange mstat_updated
   <fct>    <fct>  <int>  <int>  <dbl> <lgl>     <int>
 1 8049  1993      1      0  1992        TRUE      1
 2 8049  1994      1      0  1993        TRUE      1
 3 8049  1995     NA     NA  1994        TRUE      NA
 4 8049  1996      1      0  1994        TRUE      1
 5 8049  1997     NA     NA  1996        TRUE     NA
 6 8049  1998      1      0  1996        TRUE      1
 7 8049  1999     NA     NA  1998        TRUE     NA
 8 8049  2000      1      0  1998        TRUE      1
 9 8049  2001     NA     NA  2000        TRUE      NA
10 8049  2002      1      0  2000        TRUE      1
11 8049  2003     NA     NA  2002        TRUE      NA
12 8049  2004     NA     NA  2002        TRUE      NA
13 8049  2005     NA     NA  2002        TRUE      NA
14 8049  2006     NA     NA  2002        TRUE      NA
15 8049  2007     NA     NA  2002        TRUE      NA
16 8049  2008      1      0  2002        TRUE       1
17 8049  2009     NA     NA  2008        TRUE       NA
18 8049  2010      1      0  2008        TRUE       1
19 8049  2011     NA     NA  2008        TRUE       NA
20 8049  2012      2      1  2008        TRUE       2


dput() gives the following structure

  structure(list(ID = structure(c(4143L, 4143L, 4143L, 4143L, 4143L, 
   4143L, 4143L, 4143L, 4143L, 4143L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", 
  .............
structure(15:24, .Label = c("1979", 
"1980", "1981", "1982", "1983", "1984", "1985", "1986", "1987", 
"1988", "1989", "1990", "1991", "1992", "1993", "1994", "1995", 
"1996", "1997", "1998", "1999", "2000", "2001", "2002", "2003", 
"2004", "2005", "2006", "2007", "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", 
"2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016"), class = "factor"), mstat = c(1L, 
1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L), change = c(0L, 0L, NA, 0L, 
 NA, 0L, NA, 0L, NA, 0L), lint = c(1992, 1993, 1994, 1994, 1996, 
 1996, 1998, 1998, 2000, 2000), anychange = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
 TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), mstat_updated = c(1L, 
 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
 "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

So, after following Ben's absolutely helpful suggestions, I finally got what I wanted.

First, I fixed the lint year by year (it is probably not efficient but it worked fine anyways) where lint was not correct in the data (e.g. as Ben pointed out 2012 data - the last interview lint is 2008, but there was data from 2010 that was more recent). My example codes are:

```
df$lint_up<-ifelse(df$year==2012 & df$lint==2008 & lag(df$lint,2)==2008, 2010, df$lint)

 df$lint_up<-ifelse(df$year==2004  & df$lint==2000 & lag(df$lint,2)==2000, 2002, df$lint)

 df$lint_up<-ifelse(df$year==2000  & df$lint==1996 & lag(df$lint,2)==1996, 1998, df$lint)
```

Then I fill in the lint_updated (`lint_up`) variable:

```
mk<-df%>%
  group_by(ID)%>%
  fill(lint_up,.direction = 'up')
```

Now, for `mstat_updated`, I followed mainly Ben's suggestion but I group_by both `ID` and `lint_up`:

```
abc<-mk %>%
  group_by(lint_up, ID) %>%
  mutate(mstat_updated = ifelse(is.na(mstat) & any(last(change==0)), 
  last(mstat), mstat))
```

Comment: Can you clarify what the desired output should be in the end? (Please edit your question.)

Comment: I have added my desired output. Thanks for asking for it.

Answer (score 0):

**Edited 10/19/19**:

Thanks for adding additional information. I hope this is closer.

One `tidyverse` approach is to use fill in the `NA` values for last interview `lint` years. Using `.direction = 'up'` you will fill in based on the most recent year data.

Then, would `group_by` last interview year (`lint`), to make changes based on those years alone. This would allow you to change years 2003-2007 based on 2008 `mstat`.

One other issue I found is with 2012 data - the last interview `lint` is 2008, but it seems there was data from 2010 that was more recent.

With the most recent edit, now will do the following:

- Filter records where there is data
- Create a new variable `last_year_data` - which is similar to `lint` but would catch 2010 where there is data, but `lint` missed
- This will change NA to 0 in `change` variable - this will catch the `any(change)` to identify where `mstat_updated` should not be updated

I think this will address some of concerns - but may bring up others. If this isn't working, I don't mind either deleting my answer (in case others might more likely respond) - or you could try posting a new/revised question.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  filter(!is.na(mstat) & (mstat >= 0)) %>%
  mutate(last_year_data = lag(year)) %>%
  right_join(df) %>% 
  fill(last_year_data, .direction = 'up') %>%
  group_by(last_year_data) %>%
  mutate(mstat_updated = last(mstat),
         change = replace_na(change, 0)) %>%
  mutate(mstat_updated = ifelse(any(change > 0) & is.na(mstat), mstat, mstat_updated))

# A tibble: 34 x 7
# Groups:   last_year_data [20]
      ID  year mstat change  lint last_year_data mstat_updated
   <int> <int> <int>  <dbl> <int>          <int>         <int>
 1  8049  1983     0      0  1982           1983             0
 2  8049  1984     0      0  1983           1983             0
 3  8049  1985     0      0  1984           1984             0
 4  8049  1986     0      0  1985           1985             0
 5  8049  1987     0      0  1986           1986             0
 6  8049  1988     0      0  1987           1987             0
 7  8049  1989     0      0  1988           1988             0
 8  8049  1990     0      0  1989           1989             0
 9  8049  1991     0      0  1990           1990             0
10  8049  1992     1      1  1991           1991             1
11  8049  1993     1      0  1992           1992             1
12  8049  1994     1      0  1993           1993             1
13  8049  1995    NA      0  1994           1994             1
14  8049  1996     1      0  1994           1994             1
15  8049  1997    NA      0  1996           1996             1
16  8049  1998     1      0  1996           1996             1
17  8049  1999    NA      0  1998           1998             1
18  8049  2000     1      0  1998           1998             1
19  8049  2001    NA      0  2000           2000             1
20  8049  2002     1      0  2000           2000             1
21  8049  2003    NA      0  2002           2002             1
22  8049  2004    -5      0  2002           2002             1
23  8049  2005    NA      0  2002           2002             1
24  8049  2006    -5      0  2002           2002             1
25  8049  2007    NA      0  2002           2002             1
26  8049  2008     1      0  2002           2002             1
27  8049  2009    NA      0  2008           2008             1
28  8049  2010     1      0  2008           2008             1
29  8049  2011    NA      0  2008           2010            NA
30  8049  2012     2      1  2008           2010             2
31  8049  2013    NA      0  2012           2012            NA
32  8049  2014     3      1  2012           2012             3
33  8049  2015    NA      0  2014           2014             3
34  8049  2016     3      0  2014           2014             3
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I think it would work but there should be some modifications to `lint`.. I have edited my desired output. So, in 2002, there was an interview and before that the last interview was in 2000. However, for 2003-2007 there were no interviews.So, in 2003-2007, the `lint` should be 2002. It would be very helpful if you could let me know how to fill in `lint` for 2003-2007 with 2002 instead of 2000. Thank you.

Comment: I probably figured that out. Shouldn't that be fill(lint,.direction='up')? However, all my anychange = any(change > 0) is turning out to be `TRUE`. Please let me know how I can fix it. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. As I said my anychange column has only `TRUE` .  In fact for the entire dataset it has only `TRUE`. That is why I'm not getting correct mstat_updated. I am posting my end result for this particular observation.  Please let me know how if there is any other way for any(change>0) so that my any change variable values becomes correct. Thanks again.

Comment: Thank you so much for your helpful comments. As far as the `NA`'s are concerned in  `mstat` and `change` 2003,2005 and 2007. I later replaced the missing values with `NA` before running the code. I have edited the initial data. I have also posted some head() and  dput()..I removed most of the labels in dput(). Let me know if you need more information. Thank you so so much!

Comment: so as you mentioned confusion about 2008-2012.  As in 2010, last interview was in 2008 and also in 2010 `change` is 0, this means `mstat` from 2008 through 2010 should be same. So, `mstat_updated` in 2009 and 2010 should be `mstat(2008)`=1.

Comment: Now no interview was there in 2011. In 2012 we see `change` is 1 but we do not know if the change was made in 2011 or in 2012 itself. So, in 2011, `mstat` should be `NA` for now. (I need to look at other variables to see if `mstat` was changed in 2011.). So in your edited version, the `lint` in 2011 and 2012 should be 2010 instead if 2008 and `mstat_updated` in 2011 should be `NA`. Thanks a lot!

Comment: See most recent edits. If this isn't the right direction, I can delete the answer, or you can also try reposting/revising question. Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey Ben, I finally got what I wanted. I have added my codes in my post. I can't thank you enough for pointing me in the right direction. For two days I kept trying with `for`/`while` loop but was not in luck. Finally, your suggestions made all the difference. I really really appreciate your time and help!